# Using two or three tables in one application

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I'm a newcomer in CakePHP land.
I try to do the Post tutorial and added a extra table to the database.
I want to add record to the second table, the first table (posts) is working, but the second (cats) not.

It seems that the form is empty.
I don't get errors, it stays on the input page.

Is there somebody who can help?

VIEW

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('cat_cat');
echo $this->Form->input('naam_cat');
echo $this->Form->input('Omschrijving_cat', array('rows' => '3'));

echo $this->Form->input('image_cat', array('type' => 'file'));

echo $this->Form->end('Save Cat');

?>

CatsController
public function operation() {
            if ($this->request->is('cat')) {
    $this->Cat->create();
    if ($this->Cat->save($this->request->data)) {
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your cat has been saved.'));
    return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'nosores2'));
    }
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to add your cat.'));
    }
    }





public function detail($id) {
    if (!$id) {
        throw new NotFoudExeption(__('Invalid cat'));
    }

    $cat = $this->Cat->findById($id);
    if (!$cat) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid cat'));
    $this->set('cat', $cat);
    }
```

Comment: Have you created a Cat model? Also, in your controller, you have if($this->request->is('cat'); It should be if($this->request->is('post'); The post referred to here refers to the Http Verb POST, not the Post model of the tutorial. The if statement is checking if a form has been POSTed to the controller, if it has it will try to save the data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use saveAll or saveAssociated if the Model is linked to another model.
Depends on how your tables look like

Answer (score 0):

when you create a Form you need to put inside the name of the model:

```
echo $this->Form->create('Cat');
```